# Checking MQ authorities and MCAUSER in Linux

Tags: linux, ibm-mq, mq

I want to check all the authorities and access levels of queues and channels in my MQ-manager and check if there is a client queue or channel with administrative access. In order to do that I used `./dmpmqaut` command and I successfully dumped all the objects' authorities. However, I have two problems here:

1- There are a lot of objects in my Q-manager which has the entity of `mqm` and their authority is set to: `almqi dlt chg dsp clr`. So is this normal? I mean all I know is that the clients should not have `mqm` entity name and the authorities are not restricted at all here. Am I right?

2- I want to check all the channels and queues `MCAUSER` like what I can see in MQ-Explorer on windows. Is there any way that I can check it in Linux machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever an MQ object is created, the user who created it (or that user's primary group in non-Windows Distributed platforms) is granted all rights to the object.  In practice, this usually means that the mqm group is visible on every object when you do an auths dump.  On windows, this is often `adminID@domain` in addition to mqm.

On Linux you can do...
`echo "dis chl(*) mcauser | runmqsc [qmgrname]`
...from the command line to see what the MCAUSER is on the channels.  You can also see this using MQ Explorer.

The defined MCAUSER for all inbound channels should be one that blocks all access.  I used to recommend `nobody` but since this is potentially a valid ID on some systems, I now recommend `*nobody`.  Note that by "inbound channels" I mean those of type `RCVR`, `RQSTR`, `CLUSRCVR`, and `SVRCONN`.  By "all" I mean channels named `SYSTEM.AUTO.*`, `SYSTEM.DEF.*`, and any that you define yourself.

Make sure that an exit or a `CHLAUTH` rule maps the MCAUSER to the expected value when the connection request is authenticated.  The `CHLAUTH` rules are available on any version of MQ from 7.1 on up.  This mapping ensures that only an authenticated user or partner QMgr can connect.

If authorizations (`setmqaut` or `SET AUTHREC` commands) are defined without also defining the `CHLAUTH` rules or setting up a security exit, the effect is *worse* security, not better.  The reason being that legitimate users will *appear* to have restrictions placed on their connection but malicious users will be able to easily spoof an administrative user ID.

Please see the basic MQ Security Hardening slides at http://t-rob./net/links for more on this topic.

Comment: Thank you so much for your brief answer!